# How to have a 2 way bound OPTIONAL prop in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, two-way-binding

I would like to have an optional 2 way bound prop in vuejs. This means I don't want to have to call `testvar.sync="syncedVariable"` from the parent component as sometimes I'm just not interested in the value of `testvar` in the parent. But unless I create a variable in the parent and sync it, I cant change it from within the child. This is the recommended way to do two way bound variables according to the `vuejs` [docs](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrebjG?page=1&).

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
props: {
    testvar: {
        // this is an optional prop, it doesnt have to be specified in parent component and have testvar.sync="whatever", however thats the only way it will work?
        type: String,
        default: 'hello world'
    }   
},
data () {
    return {
    }
},
computed: {
    localVar: {
        get () {
            return this.testvar
        },
        set (nv) {
            this.$emit('update:testvar', nv)
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    click () {
        alert('Text should have changed, but it didnt')
        this.localVar = 'Text has changed'
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Don't see a real question in there.
But if I understand correctly, you could create a new variable, that you initialize in 'mounted()' with the parents value (in case you want this).

Comment: If you look at the code pen you will see it doesnt work. Theres a question there for sure. I just think needing a prop, a computed getter and setter, and a further variable in mounted is overkill. 3 variables is a mess for two way data binding on an optional prop. there must be a better way

Comment: If you imagine now that my component has many of these optional props that can be settings that sometimes i want to track and other times not and multiple that all by three it becomes a mess real quickly. seems unneccesary

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is no, there is no actual way to do this out of the box.

What needs to be done is to create an extra internal variable, then write a computed property to derive the final value.

Here is a TS example that I've done to solve the same issue:

```js
    @Prop({default: null})
    public loading: boolean | null;

    private internalLoading: boolean = false;

    private get syncLoading() {
        return (this.loading !== null) ? this.loading : this.internalLoading;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually It is possible to do 2 way binding but with some limitations. Lets assume you have a child component and have a prop on it.

```
<child :propName:"something"></child>
```

In child component you get the prop like this.

```
props : ["propName"]
```

But as you mentioned it is not 2 way binding yet. So when you try to update something, it throws a warning. But if you add :

```
model : {
    prop : "propName"
}
```

It is now actually a 2way binding. I don't know why but you can not use it with primitive types. I mean if your prop is int or string you will get the same error. But if you use an object it works. I am not sure if this is a good practice but it works. I was using angularjs before vue and this was the first thing I desperately wanted. This is the solution I found. Cheers!!